# Azure SQL custom backup role

Tags: backup, security, azure-sql-database, role

We are currently running an Elastic Pool within azure to host all our databases.
We need to back up these to on-premise as well in case of an emergency, and for it we are trying to use sqlpackage.

Now initially i tried running it with a user which only has the db_backupoperator role, however view definition was also required. However i would not like to give the backup user complete db_securityadmin permissions.

So i've tried giving the backup user only VIEW DEFINITION access by using the following command

`GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [user]`

However i am still getting the error that i do not have View Definition permissions.

I've also tried adding a custom role, however that is not supported within AzureSQL